# Add span text to selected button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have putt up a small example on codepen:
http://codepen.io/codelearner/pen/avmdvV

```
<li class="mix category-1" data-myorder="1"><a>Button 1</a></li>
```

Can someone help me create a solution so that a small span text "add"  gets added to the button that is selected or share some code snippets that could guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Barmar oh boy.. Of course I understand that but I don't know how to proceed in this case. That's why I asked if someone can share some examples or guide me in the right direction..

Comment: @CodingLearner have a look at jquery's append method http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: You use `.click()` to bind an event handler when the user clicks on it, and `.append()` to add elements to the DOM. This is basic jQuery, covered in any tutorial I'm sure.

Comment: I'd probably use a pseudo element rather than inserting a span... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epdvKe

Comment: @SexyTurnip Wow, that was a great & simple solution to this problem and works just fine. Thanks a lot!